# Azure Policy Definition Not Evaluating As Expected

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying to get an Azure Policy configured that will (for now) Audit Recovery Services Vaults for the following conditions:

1. softDeleteSettings must be "Enabled"
2. softDeleteRetentionPeriodInDays must be 14

For vaults that do in fact have these set correctly, the policy still evaluates as non-compliant. Need some guidance on my syntax because clearly it is not correct. I have tried two iterations of this and neither is producing the result I want.

**Current Attempt**

```
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/securitySettings.softDeleteSettings.softDeleteState",
                "notEquals": "Enabled"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/securitySettings.softDeleteSettings.softDeleteRetentionPeriodInDays",
                "notEquals": 14
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    }
```

**Previous Attempt**

```
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "[contains(resourcegroup().tags['exempt'], 'rv01')]",
                        "equals": false
                    },
                    {
                        "anyOf": [
                            {
                                "allOf": [
                                    {
                                        "field": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/securitySettings.softDeleteSettings",
                                        "exists": "true"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "anyOf": [
                                            {
                                                "field": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/securitySettings.softDeleteSettings.softDeleteState",
                                                "notEquals": "Enabled"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "field": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/securitySettings.softDeleteSettings.softDeleteRetentionPeriodInDays",
                                                "notEquals": 14
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "audit"
            }
        }
```

**Current Error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Audit Recovery Services Vaults for the following conditions:
>
> 1. softDeleteSettings must be "Enabled"
> 2. softDeleteRetentionPeriodInDays must be 14

There are some syntax issues in your policy. Here is the updated policy to check if both conditions are met. It will audit as **compliant**; otherwise, **non-compliant**.

```json
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "field": "tags['exempt']",
                "equals": "rv01"
              }
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/securitySettings.softDeleteSettings.softDeleteState",
                    "equals": "Enabled"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/securitySettings.softDeleteSettings.softDeleteRetentionPeriodInDays",
                    "equals": 14
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "audit"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

The policy is **compliant** if both conditions are met, like below.

[image]

The policy is **non-compliant** if both conditions are not met, like below.

[image]

**Compliance report**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that information. I copied it in and still not evaluating correctly. posted the screen shot above. The tag value error I don't care about, so I can remove that condition for now. I do not understand why the softDelete is blank though. I can clearly see it on the resources and it is in the json too.

Comment: Are you referring to the current value of 'softDeleteState' in the given screenshot, and is this the reason the policy is not auditing the resources?

Comment: correct. Not clear on why it would be seen as ---. Again, I can see the value being set in the portal and in the json view.

Comment: While asynchronous policy evaluations might take some time to update compliance data, in my case, the values are showing as expected. Here is my [policy](https://i.imgur.com/Kzfn9z8.png) and the corresponding [result](https://i.imgur.com/ZpcA8It.png). If you continue to experience the same issue, consider deleting the assignment and then reassigning it.

Comment: I hope this resolves your query?

Comment: I am not sure yet. I have not made any changes to the assignment, but will post here when I do. So far, no change.

Comment: Does it mean, Are you still facing the issue?